# Show all windows on hover/click doc icon (Mac Yosemite 10.10.5)

Tags: macos, dock

I just switched from Windows to Mac and having a hard time figuring out this.

In Windows, when I click on the application icon in task bar, it shows me all the open windows and then I can open any of the window. Is there a way to do same in Mac? Basically I want to see all the open windows when I click/hover on the open application icon in the doc.

Currently I'm doing following but not liking it -
* Use `CMD +`' to switch between open windows
* Set hotspot corner to show all windows.

But given I'm so used to click the icon to show the window, I want to do same in Mac too.

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Double tap (not click) the open application icon. This will display all open windows for that application and you can select the one you need.

If you are using a non-Apple mouse/trackpad you can right click or two-finger click an open application icon to reveal a list. The top entries are the open windows for that application. You can then select one of the open windows from that list.

Comment: You should say "right click" or "two finger click", as "double tap" can be confused to mean "double click" especially for iOS users and trackpad users

Answer (score 2):

**Using two fingers**, ***tap*** (tap not click) on ***twice*** to the application icon in the dock.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to existing solution, which is right clicking on the app icon in the Dock and clicking on the desired window:

Enable Exposé in System Preferences > Trackpad > App Exposé (for trackpad shortcut) or System Preferences > Mission Control > Application windows (for keyboard shortcut).

Then use your Exposé shortcut to show all the open windows for your *current* application. This *will not* show full screen windows. To see *other applications' windows* click that application's icons in the dock *while in Exposé mode*.

Then click the window you want to give it focus.

Exposé includes windows on other desktops and minimized windows.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer HyperDock [here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hyperdock/id449830122?mt=12) yes it costs a few Dollars but it does a load of other things too.  To be clear I do not work for them or anything.

Comment: HyperDock is perfect for this, haven't seen anything better, but unfortunately seems to have stopped working as of Ventura (13.1, build 22C65). It crashes basically on open. If anyone knows of a replacement with the same over over icon behavior, any info would be greatly appreciated.